# SQL Server : pivot table from Dynamic SQL first time with pivot

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to create a pivot table that lists the time frames (`responseText`) as columns with the average answer for each one under that particular column based on the question asked. I am trying to do this with a `PIVOT` function - to no avail.

I have the following table

[image: SQL Server table data]

I first create a temp table and populate it with values from a stored procedure, then I am building a dynamic query

```
CREATE TABLE #Data
(
    QuestionText varchar(400), 
    ResponseText varchar(200),
    AverageAnswer float

)

INSERT INTO #Data
    EXECUTE AverageDemographicGroupAnswer @GroupID, @Survey, @Demographic

--SELECT * FROM #Data
DECLARE @PivotQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Cols varchar(max)

SET @Cols =  STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(ResponseText,'[]') FROM dbo.SurveyResponses WHERE QuestionID = @Demographic  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
 --SELECT @Cols

SET @PivotQuery = 'SELECT QuestionText, '+ @Cols +' FROM 
    (
        SELECT QuestionText, ResponseText, AverageAnswer FROM #Data
    )x  
    PIVOT
    ( AverageAnswer FOR ResponseText in (' + @Cols + ')
    )p'
--select @PivotQuery
EXECUTE(@PivotQuery)

DROP TABLE #Data
```

Which produces this query

```
SELECT QuestionText, [At least 1 year but less than 3 years],[At least 3 years but less than 5 years],[Less than 1 year],[More than 5 years] FROM (SELECT QuestionText, AverageAnswer, ResponseText FROM #Data) AS SourceTable 
PIVOT( AverageAnswer FOR ResponseText in ([At least 1 year but less than 3 years],[At least 3 years but less than 5 years],[Less than 1 year],[More than 5 years])) AS PivotTable
```

but it is returning this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.

This is my first time creating a pivot and I am not sure what is wrong

Comment: The column you pivot using PIVOT syntax needs to be in an aggregate function (e.g. `MAX(AverageAnswer)` or `SUM(AverageAnswer)`).

Comment: The sproc produces the AVG  so if i remove that from the SPROC then how do i group the responses?  can you use AVG(Answer) OVER (Partition By ResponseText) inside the pivot?

Comment: Ahhh   just using MAX(AverageAnswer)  solved it   thank you very much!!